# How do I draw horizontal/vertical straight line in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, drawing

you can consider me new to GIMP. I've tried by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, can draw straight line but I want a straight **horizontal/vertical** line. So, How can I draw straight vertical/horizontal line?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key with <kbd>Shift</kbd> to restrict the angle of the straight line to multiples of 15°.

Comment: With wich drawing tool? I can't see it working (in Gimp 2.8)

Comment: You should hold both Shift _and_ Control - Shift draws a straight line, Control restricts the angles of that line.

Comment: Note that you have to push Shift before Control. If you try to push them both simultaneously, you might wind up w/the eyedropper tool.

Comment: Doesn't work with path tool.

Comment: It's Pencil (shortcut key 'N') tool. Click, then click again with shift+ctrl.

Answer (score 5):

I would create a horizontal (or vertical) guide were you want the line (with the menu Image/Guides/New Guide), then use the path tool (shortcut B).

Click on the guide where you want the first point of the segment, then click on where you want the second point of the segment. The guide will ensure the two points are aligned.

When done, click on "Stroke Path" in the tools pane and select the paint tool you want the line draw with.

Alternatively you can set the grid with the proper size and use the path tool again. I prefer guides as they are more flexible, but it depends on what you are drawing.

You won't be able to modify the line after it has been drawn as GIMP deals with bitmap images only.

Comment: This works, but it is too complicated by huge factor - @Schumacher's answer points the way the way to do it.

Comment: Convoluted, yes. But, this is the best and easisest answer I have found in researching for just drawing a `simple 1px straight horizontal dotted line`.